# Adobe Flash CS3: DataGrid component is broken?

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, adobe, flash-cs3

My datagrid component appears to be broken.

When I drag one out onto the stage, its just a square. Nothing in it. Just a square...

Then, when I tried to programmatically add it to the stage, using an example straight off the docs, it throws some errors:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/controls/DataGrid.html

```
import fl.controls.DataGrid;
var myDataGrid:DataGrid = new DataGrid();
```

Errors:

```
1172: Definition fl.controls:DataGrid could not be found.
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: DataGrid.
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method DataGrid.
```

This sounds very bad, especially considering that I need to use the DataGrid to complete my program.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? This is AS3, right in frame 1 of the main timeline.

Comment: Update: The datagrid component IS in the right place, but maybe it isnt initializing properly? How can I reinitialize it? The file is `C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS3\en\Configuration\Components\User Interface\DataGrid.swc`

Comment: Update: The rest of the components work just fine, this is the only broken one...I *really* need this working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enable "Components" panel -> drag datagrid component inside the library panel -> it should work now

Comment: Tried that, thats what I mean by the square.

Comment: hmm i did exactly the same and it compiled the swf without errors. I'm using cs4

Comment: I'm in CS3...think that could do it?